# Generating a random negative NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, nsinteger

I'm trying to generate random negative NSInteger using the following code,

```
+ (NSInteger)getNegativeRandomNumber {
    uint32_t random = arc4random_uniform(2147483647); // where 2147483647 is the max 32-bit positive value returned by random function
    return (NSInteger)(-1 * random); // convert the positive into negative number
}
```

But occasionally this code gives me positive numbers. Do you see any issue with this code?

Comment: `return -(NSInteger)random;`. The issue is because of 64 bits and 32 bits architectures, and the `NSInteger` hasn't the same definition. And you are doing the `-` sutff, on the random, and the casting.

Answer (score 2):

You get negative numbers with

```
return -(NSInteger)random;
```

You need **first** to cast to a signed type.

Comment: Probably would be good to explain why this is the case (i.e. negating an unsigned number will return an unsigned number so you need to convert to signed first).

Answer (score 0):

This will surely help....

```
-(int) generateRandomNumberWithlowerBound:(int)0
                               upperBound:(int) 2147483647
{
    int rndValue = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);
    return -(NSInteger)(rndValue);
}
```